# Passing parameters to a method and creating a deep copy

Tags: java, copy, parameter-passing

```
public class ScoreCard {  strong text  
     private double[] scores;
/** 
 * @param val
 * @param low
 * @param high
 * @return low if val < low, 
 * high if val > high, 
 * val if val is between low and high
 */

private double constrain(double val, int low, int high) {
    if (val < low)
        return low;
    if (val > high)
        return high;
    else
        return val;
    }

/**
 * DEEP copy m into scores with each item contrained between 0 and 100.
 * use method {@link this#constrain(double, int, int)}.
 * For example, if s = {-15.2, 67.4, 126.8}, scores should become
 * {0, 67.4, 100}, AND scores should be a DEEP copy of s.
 * @param s (assume s is not null)
 */

public void setMarks(double[] s) {
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] < 0 || s[i] > 100)
            constrain(s[i], 0, 100);
            this.scores[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

I have been stuck on this part of the code for a while now. As the Javadoc states, I am having trouble calling the parameters of "constrain" to "setMarks"  to set scores that are < 0 to 0 and scores > 100 to 100. I also don't think my code is correctly creating a deep copy of "s" into "scores" properly.

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're callin constrain(), but you're ignoring the constrained value that the method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are just assigning values of `s` to `scores` without taking into account the results of `constraints`. The code below should do it.

```
public void setMarks(double[] s) {
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] < 0 || s[i] > 100)
            this.scores[i] = constrain(s[i], 0, 100); // <- this solves!
        else
            this.scores[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

As an alternative, simpler and cleaner:

```
private double constrain(double val, int low, int high) {
    if (val < low)
        return low;
    if (val > high)
        return high;
    return val; // <- notice here
}

public void setMarks(double[] s) {
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
           this.scores[i] =  constrain(s[i], 0, 100); // <- notice here
    }
}
```

Comment: The if isn't even necessary. It's done by the method itself.

Comment: I see now. So I was trying to pass the array without properly passing it through the "constrain" class first? Thanks for the help

Comment: No, you were properly passing the array to the setMarks method but you were not properly setting values to the scores array using the constrain method(it is not a class).